# Bind observable collection to listbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Heres my code

```
                         ObservableCollection<product> pr = new ObservableCollection<product>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        product p = new product();
        p.PhoneMake = "Apple";
        p.PhoneModel = "4S";
        p.Price = 40;
        pr.Add(p);

        product q = new product();
        p.PhoneMake = "Apple";
        p.PhoneModel = "5S";
        p.Price = 80;
        pr.Add(q);

        lstbxProd.DataSource = pr;
```

its not updating the listbox. Do I need items source or what can i do?

I tried this too

```
     foreach (product a in pr)
        {
            lstbxProd.Items.Add(a).ToString;
        }
```

Comment: plz share your xaml code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of the Observable collection.
something like this should get you started.

```
         ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
           //Replace the lst with your control
                var lst = new List<Product>();
            products.CollectionChanged += (sender, eve) =>
            {
                switch (eve.Action)
                {

                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        //add to your control here    
                        lst.Add((Product) eve.NewItems[0]);
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                         //add implementation here
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                        break;
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                        break;
                }
            };
```